# Is anime popularity growing outside of Japan despite declining profits?

Tags: anime-history

http://www.japantimes.co.jp/news/2013/03/23/national/to-survive-anime-must-adapt-but-not-too-much/

I thought that they would make more money now that many streaming sites buy licenses from anime producers.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are looking for?

Comment: I don't know what your question is, but streaming licenses don't really make producers much money. Their business model is selling DVDs/Blu-rays. Streaming is viewed as little more than an advertisement, so streaming licenses are cheap and produce little money. Home video licenses are costly and net almost all of the profits for producers. That may change in the future, but right now that's the business model.